# web3 - solidity - wrong number of arguments error

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

I have a solidity script:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract EthProj {

    string fName;
    string age;

    event Message(string name, string age);

    function setMessage(string _fName, string _age) public {
        fName = _fName;
        age = _age;

        emit Message(_fName, _age);
    }

    function getName() public constant returns (string) {
        return (fName);
    }

    function getMessage() public constant returns (string) {
        return (age);
    }
}
```

This is my ABI `https://pastebin.com/QLBntb59`
I am setting my contract in my JS script:

```
var Web3 = require('web3'); 
    var web3 = new Web3();
    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
    var address = new String();

    var EthProjContract = web3.eth.contract(my abi);
    var EthProj = EthProjContract.at('0x1D056b1e9764D3C79ca55B68049FC906373044d8');
```

I am using my function like this:
`EthProj.setMessage($("#mes").val(), $("#name").val());`
I am calling this function using two arguments, and the function takes two arguments. I have tried re-uploading my contract to make sure it is the most recent one, and it definately is. My ABI is definitely is also up to date. How can there be this error, it was the same amount of arguments.

Comment: try `EthProj.setMessage.sendTransaction($("#mes").val(), $("#name").val(), {from: yourAccountAddress}, (e, r) => console.log(r));`

Comment: thanks @AdamKipnis, but that still doesn't work. And, what do `e` and `r` mean, do they stand for error and result?

Comment: "It doesn't work". Does that mean you got the same error message? Is your contract deployed to a testnet that I can look at? Yes, `e`, `r` are error and result. The web3js library uses error-first callback style (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#using-callbacks)

Comment: Yes, I get the same message. I am deploying it on a private network that I created on geth using these commands: `geth --datadir=./chaindata/ init genesis.json` and to start the network: `geth --datadir=./chaindata/ —-networkid 12345 —-rpc —-rpcaddr "localhost" —-rpcport 8545 —-rpccorsdomain "*" —-rpcapi “eth,net,web3,personal,admin,mine” —-nodiscover --maxpeers 0`

Comment: You have something wrong other than what is posted here. Your ABI, contract, and client code are all fine (assuming your JQuery values are correct). Everything deploys fine and runs in Truffle: `truffle(development)> EthProj.setMessage('asdf','wer', {from: a});
'0x8b91e9c0c3c63d9464acacee0832a9909d144683902b8a27de107b170646f420'
truffle(development)> EthProj.getMessage();
'wer'`

Comment: My guess at this point would be that there is an issue with your node and you're either connecting to a different node or deployed to a different node. Does your `chainId` in `genesis.json` match the network id you're passing in to `geth`? Have you restarted your `geth` node? Do you see the correct network id in the logs when starting `geth`? Finally, are you able to interact with your contract if you use `geth console/attach`?

Comment: I am back! I checked, and my `genesis.json` did have the wrong `chainid`, but after I changed my `chainID` in the `genesis.json` and made a new private net, I still get the same error. It might just be a `geth` problem, but this had worked fine for a while, until randomly stopping to work.

Comment: I tried running this command in the JS console, `EthProj.setMessage.sendTransaction("message1", "name1", {from: "0x40FDB8be71cEFC8894c1747276Cbdc704dA07DbF"}) ` and it worked! So it must be an error in my JS, what could that be.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the solution was actually quite simple. I simply had the wrong tag inside `$("#mes").val()` so it was returning undefined.